# Checkbox sits on top of the label instead of to the left of the label

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using a bootstrap multiselect plugin in my project but for some reason the checkboxes and labels are not inline. please see pic below.[image]

This is what I am trying to achienve.
[image]

Here is my HTML below.

```html
<div class="hs_cats field hs-form-field">
                <select id="catSelect" multiple="multiple">
                    {% for category in categories %}
                        <option value="{{ category.catDescription }}">{{ category.catDescription }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
```

JQuery code below.

```js
$('#catSelect').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        maxHeight: 300
    });
```

I've also included this pic below, if it helps.
[image]

Is there a simpler solution to fix this problem?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: sahre code, you probably missing something, class etc

Comment: Yes share some code!!

Comment: Refer to this post every time you want to ask a question on StackOverflow. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show the code you've done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is visible on your screenshot that your inputs take `display: block;` from your **reg_form.css** file. So they act like block elements (meaning they take up entire width of the line and prevent other elements from sitting next to them).

[image]

I would argue that you should never style `input` element directly. Cannot think of a case when a checkbox and a text input will share all the styles.

So you should change your styles to something like this:

```
.steps input[type="text"], .steps textarea {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  /* and whatever styles follow in your file */
}
```

If you have other input types (like email or password), add them separately, just like the text input (for example: `input[type="email"]`)